# C Programming type casting and sizeof()

Tags: c, gcc-warning

When i type cast and convert an double data type into an int data type and then i try to print that how much size is gonna take it shows me int size but when compiling it gives me the warning (gcc).I am wondering why it's giving me warning and how to get rid of this warning.

i have tried with structs as well but the warning still showing on compiling.
cast.c:12:11: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat=]
  printf("%d\n",sizeof(cast));
          ~^
          %ld

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    double n=0;
    //  int x=0;
    int cast;
    cast = (int) n;
    printf("%d\n",sizeof(cast));
    return 0;
}
```

i expect to find out why it is showing the warning.

Comment: Please write standard English.

Comment: The warning is very clear, `sizeof` returns a `size_t` which on your system is defined as `long unsigned int` - and `%d` is for (signed) `int` only

Comment: The type cast is also completely irrelevant for this, `sizeof` always returns a `size_t` regardless of what you pass in

Comment: The format specifier should be `%zu`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sizeof` produces a value of type `size_t`. A proper way to print it is with the format `%zu`:

```
printf("%zu\n", sizeof cast));
```

`z` is a modifier for the `size_t` type, and `u` is for unsigned, because `size_t` is unsigned. (`%d` is for signed `int`.)

Comment: Thanks!now i understand before i was confusing between data type and format specifiers.